# How can I remotely control my Android device via PC?

Tags: remote-control

How can I control my Android device from a windows PC though a HotSpot. I mean there's no Internet, no LAN and no USB between PC and Android. I'm looking for something like ShareIt, but for mirroring android screen and controlling it via PC mouse.

Comment: What have you tried? Is there some reason VLC (the first Google search result) doesn't work? It doesn't rely on Internet or USB, but you do have a LAN connection between your device and your PC if it is connected to it's hotspot.

Comment: VNC should work I thought VLC was a media player

Comment: @William Yes, I meant VNC in my first comment, not the media player software.

Answer (score 2):

For Online:

try TeamViewer. its a good remote control app from PC to PC and phone to PC and PC to phone.

[TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com)

For offline:

try AirDroid its good and it worked for me.

[AirDroid](http://airdroid.com/)

If you need just simple commands(enter text, press, perform actions):

```
adb shell input
```

text, keyevent, keyboard, mouse, joystick, touchpad, trackball, dpad and more.

Usage:

```
adb shell input text "Hello"
```

Comment: ah really? i pressed accept then edited...sorry

Comment: thanks! airDroid is fine , but it doesn't let me connect through LAN unless it uses USB & debugging , with LAN it makes every thing except screen mirroring . However,i found MirrorOp Sender for Android and MirrorOp Receiver for PC is amazing (required root ) .

Comment: ok! hope everything will work well for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found MirrorOp Sender for Android and MirrorOp Receiver for PC is an amazing app for screen mirroring (required root )